# Ignore null values patch ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Updating records using EF, but it is not updating accordingly. I just want to update only the fields that are not null and modified. In previous I'm doing like this:

```
_context.Attach(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(t);
```

which it will update all the fields and I don't want that.

Is there anything that I missed on my code?

```
    public virtual async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T t, object key)
    {
        if (t == null)
            return null;
            
        T exist = await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(key);

        if (exist != null)
        { 
            // _context.Attach(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(t); 
            _context.Attach(exist); 

            var entry = _context.Entry(t);

            Type type = typeof(T);
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (property.GetValue(t, null) == null)
                {
                    entry.Property(property.Name).IsModified = false;
                }
            }

            // _context.Attach(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(t);                  
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return exist;
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of this code? You don't need any of this to update an object. Load the object(s), modify their properties, call `SaveChangesAsync` to save all changes at once. DbContext is already a multi-entity, generic Unit-of-Work. DbSet is already a generic repository. Changes are already tracked. And that `.Set<T>()` can cause performance problems in older EF Core versions - `DbContext` will cache the metadata for all defined DbSet properties. Only EF Core 5 (or 6?) added caching to `Set<T>()` as well

Comment: `In previous I'm doing like this: _context.Attach(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(t);` why do that either? If you modify an object loaded by EF Core itself you don't need `Attach`. The object is already attached and tracked. You only need to use `Attach` to persist a detached object, eg one sent to the server with PUT. If you want to modify only changed properties, you need to find what those are. One way is to use `PATCH` instead of `PUT` and only sent the modified properties to your controller. Otherwise you have to actually load the object and check for changes

Answer (score 1):

I am using something like this

```
public virtual async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T t, object key)
{
        if (t == null)
            return null;
            
        T exist = await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(key);

        if (exist != null)
        { 
            _context.Entry(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(t);
         var result = await Context.SaveChangesAsync();               
          if (result == 0) return null
        }

    return exist;
 }
```